# Multidimensional json php

Tags: php, arrays, json, steam, steam-web-api

how can I select specific entries in a JSON file?

```
   {
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "items" : [
      {
        "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)",
        "total_items" : 923,
        "lowest_price" : "4.00",
        "highest_price" : "300.00",
        "cumulative_price" : "8722.77",
        "recent_sales_info" : {
          "hours" : "18.07",
          "average_price" : "4.21"
        }
      },
      {
        "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Redline (Minimal Wear)",
        "total_items" : 51,
        "lowest_price" : "14.26",
        "highest_price" : "100.00",
        "cumulative_price" : "1089.71",
        "recent_sales_info" : {
          "hours" : "23.37",
          "average_price" : "14.36"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

My PHP Script:

```
$steam = "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)";
$link = 'list.json';
    $string = file_get_contents($link);
    $obj = json_decode($string);
    if($obj->{'status'} == "success") die("notfound");
    $lowest_price = $obj->{'lowest_price'};
    $lowest_price[strlen($lowest_price)] = 0;
    echo $lowest_price;
```

How can I select for example the "total_items" and the "average Price" of Ak-47 Redline (Field-tested)? The market_hash_name is saved in a variable and i want to save in other variables the associated values.

Thank You.
With best Regards.
Enge

Comment: `json_decode($str, true)` gives you array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using json_decode and foreach you can achieve what you want.

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/Nkdrb), Check and let me know.

```
$json = '{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "items" : [
      {
        "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)",
        "total_items" : 923,
        "lowest_price" : "4.00",
        "highest_price" : "300.00",
        "cumulative_price" : "8722.77",
        "recent_sales_info" : {
          "hours" : "18.07",
          "average_price" : "4.21"
        }
      },
      {
        "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Redline (Minimal Wear)",
        "total_items" : 51,
        "lowest_price" : "14.26",
        "highest_price" : "100.00",
        "cumulative_price" : "1089.71",
        "recent_sales_info" : {
          "hours" : "23.37",
          "average_price" : "14.36"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}';
$result = json_decode ($json);

foreach($result->data->items as $val){
    if($val->market_hash_name == "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)")
        echo "Total Item: ".$val->total_items." AND Avg Price:".$val->recent_sales_info->average_price;
    }       
}
```

**Result is:** Total Item: 923 AND Avg Price:4.21

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much

Comment: How can I get form all entries the average_price and the total_items?

Comment: Its over there, if you need all entries just remove the in condition.